# Upper limits to chip size

Tags: integrated-circuit

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/how-are-the-finite-speed-of-light-and-the-atomic-nature-of-mater-related-to-the) on physics.stackexchange has an answer, which has a piece of information which is new to me:

> Now, you could say "OK, let's increase the chip size instead". It turns out that it's also limited. Again, cost aside (pure silicon isn't cheap), the signals must be transmitted across the chip in less than a clock cycle, so that the chip stays in sync. The information isn't travelling any faster than the speed of light, but what is the size of a chip that gets its information in less than 1/2 clock cycle at, say, 5GHz? That's 30mm. And that's assuming electric potential travels in silicon at speed of light in vacuum (it doesn't), and that's assuming it's OK to have signals 180° phase-shifted (it isn't).

Seeing as I'm doing a project on Moore's law and its limits, I found this interesting, but I don't quite understand what "the signals must be transmitted across the chip in less than a clock cycle, so that the chip stays in sync". What exactly is a "clock cycle" and what does it mean for a chip to be "in sync"? Also, does this have to do with frenquency ("5 GHz")

Comment: As a side note, making larger dies is also expensive because the probability of a defect being somewhere on the die goes up.  Wafer fabs fill the wafer, then test and throw out units that fail.  Say you have 10 defects on a wafer with 600 die.  That's a 98.3% yield.  If you double the die size, you'll only be able to fit 300 per wafer, but you have the same number of defects per wafer, dropping your yield to 96.7%.  If you increased the die size to the theoretical limit of one per wafer, it would be extremely difficult to make a wafer pure enough to avoid any defects across the entire surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clock is the fixed frequency signal that controls the logic circuitry on a chip. A clock cycle is the period (measured in seconds) of the clock.  Thus a 5 GHz clock has a  cycle time of 0.2 nanoseconds. In order for the circuitry on the chip to work properly, it is necessary (within certain limits depending on the actual chip design) for the clock signal to arrive at all points on the chip at nearly the same time. This is what it means for the chip to be in sync.  The assumption you quoted makes the assumption that the delay across the chip cannot exceed 1/2 of the clock cycle.  For a 5 GHz clock, this is 0.1 nanosecond. Since the speed of light is 300,000,000 meters second, the distance covered in 0.1 nanosecond. is 0.03 meters or 30 millimeters (mm). Slower clock speeds have larger cycle times and allow the chip to be larger and still achieve the 1/2 cycle requirement.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't actually all that difficult to design a clock distribution network that can deliver a clock with low skew across quite a large chip. (Look at pretty much any FPGA, for example.)

It also isn't difficult to deal with the latency of propagating data signals across a large chip, using pipeline registers where necessary.

So, the clock speed argument against large chips is mostly a red herring, based on overly-simplistic assumptions.

Using such techniques, systems as large as an entire wafer have been built. They are very costly, so the motivation needs to be high.

Of course, such systems have to deal with the inevitable defects that occur on any wafer, using redunancy and fault-tolerant mechanisms throughout the design.

But it's actually pretty rare to design such a system to operate completely synchronously on a single high-speed clock. Instead, individual subsystems may operate synchronously internally, but communicate asynchronously with other subsystems.

Comment: The economics of masks would also seem to constrain die size (for non-replicated designs) according to the reticle limit. Presumably common equipment is sized toward an economic/technical optimum; at some point a larger reticle would be more expensive (difficult to manufacture) than stepping more often for almost all users. Yield related to packing rectangles in a circle would also favor smaller dies (assuming partial dies are not sellable).